# Download resume in chrome is not working even if etag and accept-ranges headers are present

Tags: google-chrome, http-headers, etag, resume-download, accept-ranges

Hi I have problem with configuring my server and nginx proxy to alllow download resuming. In firefox the download is resumed sucessfully, but in Chrome it doesn't allow me to resume download.

More specificaly, the button to resume is there, but the download isn't paused at all. The browser never asks with range request. If I interrupt the network connection and try to resume download, it starts from the beginning.

Response from server from cURL log is this:

```
< server: nginx
< date: Wed, 24 Aug 2022 14:23:32 GMT
< content-type: application/zip
< content-length: 3674464996
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< access-control-allow-methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
< access-control-allow-headers: Reply-OK-Only, Content-Type, Origin, X-Requested-With, Accept
< content-disposition: attachment; filename=c98de2aa-79b7-4914-acab-f46661ecc4eb.zip
< last-modified: Wed, 24 Aug 2022 16:02:19 CEST
< accept-ranges: bytes
< etag: f9e73b20
```

Am I missing anything?

Thank you for your help.